# Setting the DELETE verb for @Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a link in ASP.NET MVC that looks like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "DELETE" })
```

However, when i click it it behaves like a GET link and chrome debugger says this: `GET http://localhost:22148/CreditCards/Delete/2001 404 (Not Found)`

The html that gets generated by the razor template is

```
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="DELETE" href="/CreditCards/Delete/2001">Delete</a>
```

It seems to be using html5 to indicate that it should be a delete call. How do I make a delete call happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript package that handles the `data-ajax` and `data-ajax-method` attributes is [The microsoft unobtrusive ajax package for jquery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/). To enable it you need to do the following.

First install the nuget package with `Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax` from the package manager console.

Then add the bundle to `RegisterBundleCollection()` in `App_Start/BundleConfig.cs` like so:

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryajax").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax*"));
```

Finally, include this bundle and the jquery bundle _Layout.cshtml:

```
dd Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
dd Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryajax")
```

While jquery is included as a nuget package with ASP.NET MVC packages, its not included in the views by default

At that point your Action link will perform a DELETE instead of a GET.